# Challenges with Django Profiles

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-allauth

I have my models as below:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=25,choices=role, default='Freelancer')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

and my view as below:

```
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'p_form': p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

and my signals file as below:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        profile.save()


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

But when I try to create a new user the profile is not created and I get **RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profile/
User has no profile.**

I have no idea why this is not working. I must also mention I am using Django allauth for my authentication

Answer (score 0):

In you're **Signal**  you're already using `create` and then again using `save` for no reason.

Try this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

No Need of two signals for saving the same incoming instance from User, the above code will create a `Profile` object the very moment a `User` object is created.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I already tried this but getting RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profile/ User has no profile error still. I am only able to create profile in Django admin not on signup. Looks like this line `p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile) ` is throwing the issues

Comment: This signal is for creating object in `profile` when `user` object is created. Updating profile instance is entirely unrelated with what you're asking. Using this code if you create a user object, you will see that corresponding profile object has been created which is linked via onetoone or foreignkey

Comment: Try adding a user in admin, with this code you'll find a profile object is created. Check that object if it has user object associated with it!

Comment: I have managed to work around this and it is now working fine. You advise on only creating signals was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your signals are not loaded so they are not called. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#receiver-functions):

> In practice, signal handlers are usually defined in a signals
>   submodule of the application they relate to. Signal receivers are
>   connected in the ready() method of your application configuration
>   class. If you’re using the receiver() decorator, import the signals
>   submodule inside ready().

So in your apps.py do something like this

```
#apps.py

class MyappConfig(AppConfig):

    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
```

Secondly make sure the `AppConfig` is being used. So in your settings.py in the INSTALLED_APPS part call your app this way:

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    myapp.apps.MyappConfig
    # ...
]
```

Two more remarks:

In the code you posted, `profile.save()` should raise an exception, as profile is not defined. However, as @ans2human pointed out, that statement is not required.

In your Profile the choices for the role have the same name as the role. This looks strange to me.

Comment: Still not working. Thank you for the feedback. I already tried this but getting RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profile/ User has no profile error still. I am only able to create profile in Django admin not on signup. Looks like this line `p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)` is throwing the issues

Comment: I did manage finally. I had done most of these but there were challenges how I had structured my signals.